# Is it possible to make user input invisible as a 'sudo' password input?

Tags: python, input, console, interaction

I'm using **raw_input()** to receive password from user in interactive mode, but I want to make input symbols invisible for security reasons, as it is when you're typing your password using *sudo* or connecting to a database. How I should do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need the [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module.

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
```